# Python Pandas Key Error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two Excel files and output a file that will let someone see the differences between the two files. I get a key error and I'm not sure how to fix it?
Currently my full code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)


old = pd.read_excel('Y:\Client Files\Client\ClientBill\March 2017\SPT List Retro Bill Mar 17.xlsx', 'List Bill', na_values=['NA'])
new = pd.read_excel('Y:\Client Files\Client\Client Bill\March 2017\Updated SPT Mar 17.xlsx', 'List Bill', na_values=['NA'])
old['version'] = "old"
new['version'] = "new"


full_set = pd.concat([old,new],ignore_index=True)



changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=[u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type',u'Sum of Premium'],keep='first')


dupe_accts = changes.set_index(u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type', u'Sum of Premium').index.get_duplicates()


dupes = changes[changes['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of Premium'].isin(dupe_accts)]


change_new = dupes[(dupes["version"] == "new")]
change_old = dupes[(dupes["version"] == "old")]


change_new = change_new.drop(['version'], axis=1)
change_old = change_old.drop(['version'], axis=1)

change_new.set_index(u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type',  u'Sum of Premium',inplace=True)
change_old.set_index(u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type',  u'Sum of Premium',inplace=True)


diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old,df2=change_new))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)



changes['duplicate']=changes[u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type', u'Sum of Premium'].isin(dupe_accts)

removed_accounts = changes[(changes["duplicate"] == False) & (changes["version"] == "old")]


new_account_set = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=[u'Employee ID',u'Benefit Plan Type',u'Sum of Premium'],take_last=False)


 new_account_set['duplicate']=new_account_set[u'Employee ID', u'Benefit Plan Type', u'Sum of Premium'].isin(dupe_accts)


added_accounts = new_account_set[(new_account_set["duplicate"] == False) & (new_account_set["version"] == "new")]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("my-diff-2.xlsx")
diff_output.to_excel(writer,"changed")
removed_accounts.to_excel(writer,"removed",index=False,columns=[u'Employee ID',u'Benefit Plan Type',u'Sum of Premium'])
added_accounts.to_excel(writer,"added",index=False,columns=[u'Employee ID',u'Benefit Plan Type',u'Sum of Premium',])
writer.save()
```

The error I get has to do with the dupes variable.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ClientBill2.py", line 24, in <module>
dupes = changes[changes['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of 
Premium'].isin(dupe_accts)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2059, in 
__get
item__
return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2066, in 
_geti
tem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1386, in 
_ge
t_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3543, 
in g
et
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2136, in 
get
_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.Py
ObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.Py
ObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: ('Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of Premium')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally typed "changes" twice.

Try modifying

```
dupes = changes[changes['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of Premium'].isin(dupe_accts)]
```

to

```
dupes = changes[['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type', 'Sum of Premium']].isin(dupe_accts)
```

Comment: That was easy. Now I'm getting attributeerror: list object has no attribute isin

Comment: @TroyR Sorry, I missed to correct the placement of the second bracket. I updated the answer with the correct line.

Comment: Could that be the same issue with the change_new variable?

Comment: @TroyR I don't know what issue you are having with the `change_new` variable. The error message you posted in the question is only related to the issue addressed in this answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. It looks like the code I'm working on has some work that needs to be done to get in to run. I'm in the process of making some changes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @TroyR No worries, please consider upvoting or accepting this answer if it was helpful for you. If you end up having additional questions, post them separately, but please feel to link to the new question here.

Comment: One thing I'm  trying to figure out is how to remove dups when I look at three columns in a dataframe. I've posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213467/trying-to-drop-duplicates-from-pandas-dataframe