# Trying to drop duplicates from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that concatenates two dataframes then I'm trying to drop all duplicates based on 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd

old = pd.read_excel('Old.xlsx')
new = pd.read_excel('New.xlsx')
old['version'] = 'old'
new['version'] = 'new'

full_set = pd.concat([old,new],ignore_index=True)

changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Plan', 'Sum'], keep='first')
```

The problem I'm running into is when I run

```
len(changes)
```

I get 4013, which based doing basically the same thing in Excel I would expect the length to be 371 - since there are 371 values when looking at those three rows that are only in one of the files.

Here is the info from new

```
u'Employee ID': [101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  103421L,
  103421L,
  103421L],
 u'Benefit Plan Type': [u'Vision',
  u'Basic Life and AD&D',
  u'Medical and Rx',
  u'Dental',
  u'Health Advocate',
  u'Long Term Disability',
  u'Short Term Disability',
  u'Vision',
  u'Basic Life and AD&D',
  u'Medical and Rx'],
u'Sum of Premium': [11.63,
  49.49,
  876.33,
  51.44,
  0.8,
  36.96,
  0.0,
  6.63,
  15.93,
  438.17],
```

And old:

```
 u'Employee ID': [101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  101444L,
  103421L,
  103421L,
  103421L],
u'Benefit Plan Type': [u'Vision',
  u'Basic Life and AD&D',
  u'Medical and Rx',
  u'Dental',
  u'Health Advocate',
  u'Long Term Disability',
  u'Short Term Disability',
  u'Vision',
  u'Basic Life and AD&D',
  u'Medical and Rx'],
u'Sum of Premium': [11.63,
  49.49,
  876.33,
  51.44,
  0.8,
  36.96,
  0.0,
  6.63,
  15.93,
  438.17],
```

Comment: There might be differences in whitespace which makes Pandas think similar values are unequal. Or perhaps one DataFrame has a column of strings while the other has a column of `ints`. It's impossible to say definitively how to fix the problem without seeing `old` and `new`.  For more specific help post a slice of `old` and `new` which demonstrate the problem. For instance, something like `old.head(10).reset_index().to_dict('list')` and `new.head(10).reset_index().to_dict('list')`.

Comment: @unutbu Just added the two to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for posting snippets, but do they demonstrate the issue? If not, look in `changes` for a line or two that should have been dropped, and find the associated lines in `old` and `new`. For example, if the duplicate lines have `ID = 101444` and `Sum of Premium = 0.0` then you could isolate the relevant lines in `old` using `old.loc[(old['ID']=101444) & old['Sum of Premium']=0.0].reset_index().to_dict('list')`. Then post that and a similar snippet from `new`. If the snippets demonstrate the issue, then we should be able to identify and fix it.

Comment: @unutbu I can't get that to run in Jypter. It says there is a syntax error at the first =

Comment: Oops, I forgot a set of parentheses and used `=` when it should have been `==`. It should have been `old.loc[(old['ID']==101444) & (old['Sum of Premium']==0.0)].reset_index().to_dict('list')`. This is only an example, however. You may need to do additional slicing / sub-selecting of some sort to make the snippet short enough to post.

Comment: @unutbu I have the result from both dataframes. What would I be looking for to see why it's not getting dropped? Those three columns look to be the same in both.

Comment: @unutbu I think my code is working, it's just not what I need. Looking into other options right now